# Iterate nested dictionary and replace all tuples with one of its elements, keeping dictionary structure

Tags: python, dictionary

I've seen other questions about iterating nested dictionaries, but nothing quite like what I'm trying to do. Take the following nested dictionary, which may also have lists as their innermost values.

```
d = {(1, 2) : {(3, 4) : [(5, 6), (7, 8)]}, (9, 10) : {(11, 12) : (13, 14)}}
```

I want to replace every tuple with either its first element, or second element (my choice). So if I choose first element, I would get the following dictionary:

```
d = {1 : {3 : [5, 7]}, 9 : {11 : 13}}
```

And if I chose the second element, I would get

```
d = {2 : {4 : [6, 8]}, 10 : {12 : 14}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: People will be less and less willing to answer your questions when you never select a correct answer, or even up-vote. You have 0 votes and no completed questions here — have *none* of the answers people submitted to your questions ever helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going this route:

```
level1 = {(1, 2) : {(3, 4) : [(5, 6), (7, 8)]}, (9, 10) : {(11, 12) : [(13, 14)]}}

i = 0 # or i = 1
for k1, level2 in list(level1.items()):
    for k2, level3 in list(level2.items()):
        for j, value in enumerate(level3):
            level3[j] = value[i]
        level2[k2[i]] = level2.pop(k2)
    level1[k1[i]] = level1.pop(k1)
```